# How do you create another Xubuntu live USB from a live USB?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, live-usb

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS live USB (non-persistent) and from it I want to create another Xubuntu 20.04 LTS live USB on another USB.

So far I've tried Mkusb and UNetbootin and both are not booting. Mkusb just boots into the system OS and UNetbootin shows that initial blue screen with "default" as the first option and the countdown, but loops there, counting down to 1 and going back to 10. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSmZb.png) is the screen I see. Notice there should be more options.

I've tried both methods several times with same results.

Any pointers?

EDIT (UPDATE): Turned out the .iso file was corrupt. Redownloaded another one and it worked out. Thanks all.

Comment: So you want to clone USB basically? Edit: https://superuser.com/questions/1041163/how-do-i-clone-a-usb-stick-including-partitions

Comment: Try Balena Etcher in your live USB environment. You can download the .ISO again while in the live environment, it'll temporarily save it. Then, just use Etcher to create a new USB - making sure you pick the right USB drive to write it on. It should work like a champ.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) (It is a good idea to start by checking that the iso file was downloaded correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

So, what did you do exactly? Did you:

- Boot from the USB live Xubuntu
- Re-Download the *.ISO file
- apt install some USB disk creator
- run it
- point it to the ISO and your secone USB stick
- Let it do its work and then reboot using the new stick only
  ?
  If yes, then I son't know :) Then, you should maybe just copy the original stick or use the original OS which created your first stick to create the second one.

If no, please do :)

Hope I could help. I'm open for other questions though.

-- Streunekater

Comment: The 2nd step did the tick. It was a currupt .iso file. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I'll suggest you to use [Ventoy](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy). Awesome program to create live USB inside Linux. Thank You

Comment: It is a git based repository. Clone and use it.

Comment: There is no package called ventory in Ubuntu repositories. Additionally, this question does not explain how this software can be used to answer the question that was asked. **If you are suggesting software that's not in Ubuntu repositories, you should include instructions for obtaining and installing this software**. Your answer should also provide a solution to the question that was asked. After telling us how to obtain the software, I suggest that you also **explain the steps you need to take in this software to answer the question**.

Comment: @Nmath Pooja is erroneously referring to the [Ventoy](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy) open source tool to create bootable USB drives for ISO/WIM/IMG/VHD(x)/EFI files.Ventoy is basically a good tool.